# Unable to run phpunit to test laravel on Windows 10

Tags: windows, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I have laravel 5.1 installed on a windows 10 machine. Laravel 5.1 comes pre installed with phpunit

I can see that it exist in vendor\bin directory - both phpunit and phpunit.bat

When I run the `phpunit` command from from the root of my laravel project I get the following error:

> phpunit 
>       Cannot run program "phpunit" (in directory "C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I tried the following `vendor/bin/phpunit` and i get the following error:

> vendor/bin/phpunit
>       Cannot run program "C:\wamp\www\laravel\leavetracker-5.1\vendor\bin\phpunit" (in directory "C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I've attempted to add phpunit as a environment variable aswell but it still doesnt work:

```
C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject\vendor\bin;
```

Comment: have you tried to lauch `phpunit.bat`?

Comment: @ matteo. at the root of the project i run the following `> vendor/bin/phpunit.bat` i get error `PHPUnit 4.8.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F

                                                              
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]     
  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! `

Comment: in my php.ini file i've added `xdebug.max_nesting_level=300` restarted all services, re issued command `vendor/bin/phpunit.bat` but i still get `Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached`

Comment: hi, check if you are modified the correct php.ini (some time exist one for the web server and one for the shell).

Comment: you can launch the `php -i` command  and check for the `php.ini`string,  or you can do   `php -i |grep 'php.ini'` if you have the grep command

Comment: @ matteo. Thanks. looks like i updated the wrong php.ini file. I've managed to get it working now by adding the `xdebug.max_nesting_level=300` to the correct php.ini file.

Comment: Hi, I summarized our comments in the answer above. Feel free to accept and or upvote if you retain it useful

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the comment, you can execute the command as follow:

```
> vendor/bin/phpunit.bat
```

Check the php.ini config files for correct configuration of the CLI, executing the command:

```
> php -i
```

An search for `php.ini` string.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use on windows 10

```
C:\code\laravel-project> vendor\bin\phpunit
```